# Deleting a document that matches a query in pymodm

Tags: mongodb, pymodm

Please help, been stuck for hours, how do I delete a document that matches a query directly in pymodm.

For example:

```
user = User.objects.raw({'name':'Moses'})
```

How do I delete this user from my database collection?

Comment: Have you tried [delete()](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#pymodm.MongoModel.delete)?

Comment: It's in a queryset so it doesn't work, but i found a workaround so i'm good. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

you can use the delete() method to delete document from the MongoDB, try the below code this worked for me fine.

```
user = User.objects.raw({'name':'Moses'})
user.delete()
```